# Get symbol at mouse position

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction

How can I get the symbol which is under the mouse pointer at any time?

I know that I can get the mouse position with `MousePosition[]` and dynamically with `Dynamic[MousePosition[]]`. However I was not able to find a way to get the symbol at this position.

My final goal is to create a second notebook which always shows the current value of the symbol which is under the mouse pointer.

Comment: Is this the sort-of thing you have in mind? `a = 4; Mouseover[HoldForm[a], a]` ?

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides Unfortunately not. I would like it to work without `Mouseover`. Currently I'm also looking into `SelectionMove`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an attempt at something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0olK.gif]

```
Dynamic@Row@{$sym, " = ", Symbol@$sym}

Unprotect@FE`CacheTemplateAndUsage;
FE`CacheTemplateAndUsage[sym_String] /; Context@arg == "Global`" :=
 (
  $sym = sym;
  MathLink`CallFrontEnd@
   FrontEnd`CacheTemplateAndUsagePacket[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], sym,
     Null]
  )
```

The symbol name and its value is displayed in the top cell after hovering over a symbol for a few seconds. Some notes:

- This is using undocumented functionality, so use it at your own risk (it might also break at any moment)
- The idea is to intercept the call the front-end makes to get the usage information for a symbol. After this is successful once, it will never be done again, so we need to make sure to always return an empty usage
- Currently it is limited to symbols in the global context, since for system symbols you probably want to see the info dropdown
- The front-end needs to think that a value is assigned to the symbol (or something like that, not quite sure on the specifics). Usually any symbol with a definition should fall into this category, but in some circumstances the front-end is not aware of existing symbol definitions.

Comment: Clever usage of ``FE`CacheTemplateAndUsage``! I would never have thought to intercept that

Comment: I also had the same idea but I did not find the right functions to override. Did you use LinkSnooper? Can you also add the code to your text for easy copy pasting, please?

Comment: This is a great answer. However it is unfortunate that we lose the usage documentation. I don't think that writing a custom code completion overlay is worth the effort?! (suggestions are welcome). Currently I'm using code selection and `Dynamic` for my purposes.

Comment: @Qbyte Completely forgot about the code, sorry! I have added it now. And yes, I used LinkSnooper for this - I remembered seeing something in there when hovering over symbols, from there it was quite easy to find the exact call.

Comment: As for the documentation: Yes, that's unfortunately a side-effect of this approach, and seems impossible to fix (essentially, you only get the call if the front-end doesn't know the usage, and you can have the popup if the front-end doesn't know the usage). You might be able to use [`ResourceFunction["InformationPopup"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InformationPopup) to recover  the lost functionality however (or at least something comparable)